# Add MySQL.Data.RT.dll Reference to Windows Store App Project in Visual Studio 2013 C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, mysql-connector

i want to use the mysql-connector/net (6.9.5) in my windows 8.1 app (Visual Studio 2013, C++) connecting my Database.
But i can't reference the MySql.Data.RT.dll. Here the error-message:

Microsoft Visual Studio
Could not add a reference to:
C:\develop\mysqlConnectorNet\RT\MySql.Data.RT.dll
For one of the following reasons:

- Targets a higher version of the .NET Framework
- Not a .NET assembly
- Not a registered ActiveX control

In C# it is working:
https://blogs.oracle.com/MySqlOnWindows/entry/how_to_using_connector_net
Also tried MySql C++ Connector -> no success.

Any ideas how i can access my MySql-Database from a Windows 8.1 App written in C++?

Thanks for help!